# How to constantly check GPS Signal strength

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, core-location

I want to display GPS Signal Strength in the form of image like:
[image]
But I can't find any documentation about this or example.
I have tried this:

```
if (self.locationManager.location.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        {
            ...@"No"];
        }
        else if (self.locationManager.location.horizontalAccuracy > 163)
        {
            ...@"Poor"];
        }
        else if (self.locationManager.location.horizontalAccuracy > 48)
        {
            ...@"Average"];
        }
        else
        {
            ...Full
        }
```

But it seams that this code does nothing.
How can I monitor GPS signal strength, is it possible?

Comment: have you placed this in one of the delegate methods of locationManager and have you set the delegate for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is this code located? Your code should be in the delegate callback:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

or iOS 6.0 and above:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Comment: Cool I put this in (void)locationManager... and now I get data all the time. I hope that this is a good method to monitor GPS signal. Thanks.

Comment: This is the [recommended](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) method

Comment: So this code that I write is not? What part of this documentation tells about monitoring signal strength?

Comment: The code that I posted is correct for getting the user's location. I added the link to the Apple documentation for further reading. Note that you cannot infer GPS signal strength from it, though, since location tracking involves a variety of technologies on the devices, including GPS.

Comment: Your code is right and you could monitor gps strength like this, since: "The radius of uncertainty for the location, measured in meters". Your approach is suitable here